# How do I compile on a Mac?

Tags: c, macos, compilation

I'm trying to Compile my C program I have on my Mac.

I've been using Codepad.org to check that my Code works, but Codepad doesn't let me input my own values.

I need a Compiler that lets me input my own values, and I can save the Output as a txt file (to submit to my Professor).

Answer (score 2):

2 possible ways,

1. get [xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/), which includes gcc.
2. install macports, and use macports to install gcc.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `Terminal` app with `gcc`.

You can then run by appending `./` before the program name and `>` to save the output.

`gcc -Wall program.c -o program`

This will compile with all warnings (`-Wall`) with executable name `program` (`-o`).

run `./program > textfile.txt` and this will put the output in a file.

(You might have to install Xcode and command line tools depending on your OS version)

Comment: I believe you need to install Xcode and the Command Line Tools. Mac OS does not ship with gcc. gcc might not even come with xcode anymore, xcode uses clang.

Comment: `gcc` just invokes Clang in recent versions.